# Is there a way to save the changes of tools bars in LibreOffice writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I'd like to know this...becuase in the near future I might wanna export the changes I have just made to LibreOffice writer and import those changes to another computer.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have made changes in your Libreoffice Writer's toolbar *(I'm running Libre office 3.5)* like 
Eg:

*add "**Load URL"** from **Tools > Customize > Toolbars***

[image]

I think these changes are saved in the following folder:

```
/home/user/.config/libreoffice/3/user/config/soffice.cfg/modules/swriter/toolbar
```

In my case I have an xml file named **standardbar.xml**

So you can backup your .xml files and transfer them to the same folder but in another machine.

**Note:**
The same if for the others tools like Calc, Impress, Draw. They have their folders in

```
/home/user/.config/libreoffice/3/user/config/soffice.cfg/modules/
```

Hope this will helpful!

Cheers.

Comment: hey Roman. Thanks for the reply. 
In that folder (/soffice.cfg/modules/swriter/toolbar), I have 3 files. Insertbar.xml, standardbar.xml and textobjectbar.xml. There is nothing libreoffice writer specific....I'll copy these and try to import my current settings onto another system in my virtual machine.

Comment: Ok, I tested this in the same way in a virtual machine. The specific folder es "swriter" for Libreoffice Writer or scalc for libreoffice Calc inside of soffice.cfg/modules folder. The files in xml format are for specific kind of toolbar that you have customized, eg: standard, insertbar.

Comment: Roman..thanks a lot. Your instruction was very helpful to locate the file that is responsible for the menu changes. I'd like to add that if on one computer someone adds an extra menu bar, it is not enough to copy the corresponding file to make that specific menu appear on computer (or after a reinstall). You will also have to add manually the menu bar in libreoffice.

Comment: Glad to help Elysium!, and regarding to the menubar,that's weird, I created a menubar called  "test" and it's appear in the virtual machine too. But make sure that if you have a menubar copy the xml in "/.config/libreoffice/3/user/config/soffice.cfg/modules/swriter/menubar" not in ".config/libreoffice/3/user/config/soffice.cfg/modules/swriter/toolbar".

Comment: ok, I look into it and edit my comment. Thanks.